# Laravel and ngrok: url domain is not correct for routes and assets

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead, ngrok, vagrant-share

My setup:

- Homestead on Mac OSX with multiple sites configured
- I have one site setup using domfit.test as the local domain (auto mapped using hostsupdater)

My problem:

If I `vagrant ssh`, and then `share domfit.test` I get a random generated ngrok url as you'd expect (http://whatever.ngrok.io), however when I access this URL all my resources / routes are being prefixed with `http://domfit.test/` (http://domfit.test/login for instance)

I've tried the following:

- Setting APP_URL as the ngrok URL
- `php artisan config:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `{{ url('login') }}`
- `{{ route('login') }}`

My understanding is that `url()` should return the actual URL that the browser requested (rather than using `APP_URL`) but it always returns `domfit.test`.

If I rename my site in `Homestead.yaml` (for example to `newdomfit.test`) and re-provision then this is the domain that `url()` and `route()` uses, regardless of my `APP_URL`. So the `Homestead.yaml` seems to be forcing that domain. Which begs the question - how are you meant to actually use the share functionality?

I'm new to Laravel so I am not sure if all of this is expected behavior and I am misunderstanding something?

I just want my links and resources in templates to work for local (`domfit.test`), shared (`ngrok`) and eventually production with the same piece of code. My worry is I will have to change all of my `route()` or `url()` references when I attempt to put this website live.

**EDIT BELOW**

OK I've just tried again. Changed `APP_URL` for `ngrok`:

Searched my entire codebase for `domfit.test`, and only some random session files seem to have references:

code/domfit/storage/framework/sessions/

```
APP_NAME=DomFit
APP_VERSION=0.01
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=XXXX
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://04b7beec.ngrok.io
```

Then in my Controller I have it doing this for some simple debugging:

```
echo(url('/login'));
echo(route('login'));
echo($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
echo($_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST']);
```

If I use the `ngrok` URL the output I get is:

```
http://domfit.test/login
http://domfit.test/login
domfit.test
04b7beec.ngrok.io
```

I don't understand how `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is returning the wrong url?

It looks like it could be related to this: https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/342

**ANOTHER EDIT**

It looks like it has to do with Homestead's `share` command:

```
function share() {
if [[ "$1" ]]
then
    ngrok http ${@:2} -host-header="$1" 80
else
    echo "Error: missing required parameters."
    echo "Usage: "
    echo "  share domain"
    echo "Invocation with extra params passed directly to ngrok"
    echo "  share domain -region=eu -subdomain=test1234"
fi
```

}

Which passes the option `-host-header` to `ngrok` which according to their documentation:

> Some application servers like WAMP, MAMP and pow use the Host header for determining which development site to display. For this reason, ngrok can rewrite your requests with a modified Host header. Use the -host-header switch to rewrite incoming HTTP requests.

If I use `ngrok` without it, then the website that gets displayed is a different one (because I have multiple sites configured in Homestead) - so I'm still not sure how to get around this. For the time being I could disable the other sites as I'm not actively developing those.

Comment: What is the exact value of APP_URL in your .env file? Maybe even paste the whole line.

Comment: please add your .env file

Comment: Just a troubleshoot tip, just search your whole project for `domfit.test` and see where it is being used. :)

Comment: I've just updated the original question with some more information. Any more suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: @DominicWilliams I'm running into the exact same issue did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @DominicWilliams Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem. I don't understand the discussion here, but it seems related: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18613

Comment: @HelenChe Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Ryan unfortunately not, which is a shame because this testing tool is almost perfect.

Comment: @Ryan I know you were looking a while ago, but in case you're still looking for an answer, I've given one below.

Comment: @HelenChe I know you were looking a while ago, but in case you're still looking for an answer, I've given one below.

Comment: @patricus Thanks! I'll take a look at this next time I run into this problem.

Answer (score 31):

#### Update for ngrok 3.0+

ngrok 3.0 stopped using the `X-Original-Host` header and started using the `X-Forwarded-Host` header.

Therefore, if using ngrok 3.0+ with TrustedProxies set to trust all proxies (`protected $proxies = '*';`), then there should be nothing else that needs to change.

However, if not using TrustedProxies, all the below information is still relevant, just replace any references of `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST` with `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`.

#### For ngrok < 3.0

Even though you're going to the ngrok url, the host header in the request is still set as the name of your site. Laravel uses the host header to build the absolute url for links, assets, etc. ngrok includes the ngrok url in the `X-Original-Host` header, but Laravel doesn't know anything about that.

There are two basic solutions to the issue:

1. update the request with the proper server and header values, or
2. use the `forceRootUrl()` method to ignore the server and header values.

---

**TrustedProxies and Forwarded Host**

If you're using TrustedProxies (default in Laravel >= 5.5), and you have it configured to trust all proxies (`protected $proxies = '*';`), you can set the `X-Forwarded-Host` header to the `X-Original-Host` header. Laravel will then use the value in the `X-Forwarded-Host` header to build all absolute urls.

You can do this at the web server level. For example, if you're using apache, you can add this to your `public/.htaccess` file:

```
# Handle ngrok X-Original-Host Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Original-Host} \.ngrok\.io$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST:%{HTTP:X-Original-Host}]
```

If you prefer to handle this in your application instead of the web server, you will need to update the Laravel request. There are plenty of places you could choose to do this, but one example would be in your `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method:

```
public function boot(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    if ($request->server->has('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST')) {
        $request->server->set('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST', $request->server->get('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'));
        $request->headers->set('X_FORWARDED_HOST', $request->server->get('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'));
    }
}
```

---

**Not Using TrustedProxies**

If you're not using TrustedProxies, you can't use the `.htaccess` method. However, you can still update the server and headers values in your application. In this case, you'd need to overwrite the Host header:

```
public function boot(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    if ($request->server->has('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST')) {
        $request->server->set('HTTP_HOST', $request->server->get('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'));
        $request->headers->set('HOST', $request->server->get('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'));
    }
}
```

---

**Using `forceRootUrl()`**

If you don't want to modify any headers or the Laravel request, you can simply tell the URL generator what root url to use. The URL generator has a `forceRootUrl()` method that you can use to tell it to use a specific value instead of looking at the request. Again, in your `AppServiceProvider::boot()` method:

```
public function boot(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    if ($request->server->has('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST')) {
        $this->app['url']->forceRootUrl($request->server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO').'://'.$request->server->get('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Laravel 5.8 without any modification, only the last two methods seem to work. Named route results in http instead of https.

Comment: To overcome this http thing, I need to trust all proxies by editing TrustProxies.php file in app\Http\Middleware\. Simply add "*" to protected $proxies, line 15. This edit surprisingly makes all methods described by patricus work. Any security concern about all this thing?

Comment: Best Answer ever.

Comment: Best Answer ever !!

Comment: 這回答是最佳的答案。

先講作法：
1. 找到 `app\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php `
2. 將 `protected $proxies;`  改為 `protected $proxies = '*';`

 因為 `route('name')` 的結果是否為 `https` 取決於 `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` 這個檔案的 `isSecure()`，如果你使用的是 laravel sail, valet 為開發環境，那麼你必需將 forward 的 ip 位置加入Proxies 的名單中。

Comment: in Newer versions of Ngrok change HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST  with HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST

Comment: @GursharnSingh I've updated the answer with information related to the update in ngrok 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the protocol with the last @patricus solution using this:

```php
$this->app['url']->forceScheme('https');
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the already given answer. Where is the difference?

Comment: Its complementary. If you only force the root, the generated URL will use http instead of https as @Rivo said.

Comment: This was helpful and should be apart of main answer.. if you're using Https locally.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up for my `<base>` tag ngrok issue:

```
<base href="{{request()->isSecure() ? 'https' : 'http'}}://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'] ?? request()->getHttpHost() }}">
```

Answer (score -2):

I has similar issue and resolved it as below

In AppServiceProvider.php add below check inside `boot()`

```
if (!empty( env('NGROK_URL') ) && $request->server->has('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST')) {
            $this->app['url']->forceRootUrl(env('NGROK_URL'));
        }
```

Also in your `.env` add below entry

```
NGROK_URL=xxxx.ngrok.io
```

Full doc of the solution ([link](https://vanrossum.dev/5-using-ngrok-with-laravel))

Answer (score -3):

In your app.config and .env file, try changing it to:

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),