# Laragon's Quick Share with Ngrok not working as expected

Tags: ngrok, laragon

So, I tried Laragons Quick Share to share my localhost website so that others can proofread it. But when accessing the site it shows the following error:

[image: Ngrok error]

So I signed up and installed an authtoken and entered that authtoken in the myproject.yml file. But now I get this instead when entering the Ngrok URL:

[image: Laragon]

Adding /myproject.com after the Ngrok URL doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Configure your Ngrok account
https://ngrok.com/

Add your Authtoken and assign the region

[image][image]

Manually use the command in the laragon cmder terminal

```
ngrok http --host-header=laravelapp.test 80
```

Problem VITE

Styles and JS
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194923/laravel-and-ngrok-url-domain-is-not-correct-for-routes-and-assets/54488972#54488972)

Generate url and add .env

```
NGROK_URL=https://aa11-bb22-cc33-dd44-ee55-ff66-gg77-00-hh88.ngrok-free.app
```

add into app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['url']->forceRootUrl(env('NGROK_URL'));
    // ...
}
```

run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

run with vite

```
npm run dev
```

[image]

[image]